# how to get Device Token using Iphone Application and other info about the device?

Tags: iphone, device, token

In my iphone application i want Device Token using the APN.
How to get that using code ?

Alos i want Other information about the Device User,its version and other info.
How to get that using Code ?

Is it possible to get the device other information using Device Token?

what is the format of the Device Token?

Please give solution by code or any link or any other way,which would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Mishal Shah

Answer (score 7, accepted):

here how you get information about device---

```
NSString*  deviceName= [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
NSString*  localizedModel=[[UIDevice currentDevice] localizedModel];
NSString*  systemVersion=[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
NSString*  systemName=[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemName];
NSString*  model=[[UIDevice currentDevice] model];
```

Comment: Yes, but it is still must be used with APN.  Token from APN may be changed, you cannot rely on it to identify your device for provider. You should get unique Id AND APN token Id and send them to provider on registration.

Answer (score 15):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert ];
}

// Delegation methods 
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSLog(@"didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: %@", deviceToken);
}
```