# device token without method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, apple-push-notifications

Can we get device token without calling method in ipad?

if yes how?

Thanks,
shyam paramar

Comment: without calling which method?

Comment: here is the answer of Costique and Viren Shakya  comment.
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513037/how-to-get-device-token-using-iphone-application-and-other-info-about-the-device)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **have** to call the

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge)];`

method to trigger the registration of your app and the specific device with the Apple Push Notification Service.

It's described in the *'Local & Push Notifications Programming Guide'* under Scheduling, Registering and Handling Notifications.